# How to quote & bill as a subcontractor

Tags: contracts, design, subcontracting, partner

I'm curious to hear if anyone has any experience as a subcontractor partnering with another business/contractor and if so how you go about setting parameters around each project.

I've been approached by a local graphic design firm to help them with a website they're currently working on. Their client has asked for a few things that will require some programming and the design firm has asked if they could hire me to take care of these items.

- Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how you go about quoting out such work?
- If you establish a contract between yourself and the firm you're being hired by?
- If you do use a contract, what does it generally look like?
- Do you have any sort of general agreement between yourself and the other party which can be used as a sort of "running" agreement for this type of work?

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 6):

You quote the hiring company exactly like a customer, be it fixed price or hourly fee, and you bill them. It may be the case that the hiring company takes a commission, don't be worried (but don't lower your prices for this reason).

You absolutely establish a contract with this firm. You can make it longer term than for the initial project if you want, but having a first "test" run is convenient. The contract will be similar to any service contract. It may or not include specific clauses about the end customer, depending on the situation.

You don't establish a direct contract with the end customer. Make sure that the respective responsibilities of the two service providers are clearly stated and don't accept risks that are not yours. (In particular, the main contractor not being paid by the customer is not a valid reason not to pay you.)